# How to fix the width and height of the window using curses in Python?

Tags: terminal, ncurses, python-curses, pdcurses

According to this link, https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html, the description for `curses.resizeterm()`, it should be possible to fix the width and height of my terminal window to a fixed values of my interest, no? I wrote a simple code below

```py
import curses

def main( stdscr ):
    stdscr.resizeterm( 20, 20 )
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr( 10, 10, "o" )
    stdscr.refresh()
    curses.napms( 3000 )
    
curses.wrapper( main )
```

But it returns the error message `AttributeError: '_curses.window' object has no attribute 'resizeterm'`. If I remove the `resizeterm` line, it works fine, but of course the size of the screen is not necessarily 20 by 20! If I put it in front of `curses` instead of `stdscr`, then it gives a similar error message again `AttributeError: module 'curses' has no attribute 'resizeterm'`. How should one use this `resizeterm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's documentation needs some work, but basically the problem is that it's used for two different underlying implementations:

- [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resize_term) provides `resizeterm` and `resize_term` entrypoints, but those *respond* to `SIGWINCH` (a longstanding *nix feature but only recently quasi-standardized):

> The function **`resizeterm`** resizes the standard and current windows (i.e.,
> *`stdscr`*  and  *`curscr`*)  to  the  specified  dimensions, and adjusts other
> bookkeeping data used by the ncurses library  that  record  the  window
> dimensions such as the *`LINES`* and *`COLS`* variables.

- [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/docs/MANUAL.html) has a `resize_term` function which can resize the window:

> `resize_term()` is effectively two functions: When called with nonzero values for *nlines* and *ncols*, it attempts to resize the screen to the given size. When called with (0, 0), it merely adjusts the internal structures to match the current size after the screen is resized by the user. On the currently supported platforms, SDL, Windows console, and X11 allow user resizing, while DOS, OS/2, SDL and Windows console allow programmatic resizing. If you want to support user resizing, you should check for **`getch()`** returning **`KEY_RESIZE`**, and/or call is_termresized() at appropriate times; if either condition occurs, call resize_term(0, 0). Then, with either user or programmatic resizing, you’ll have to resize any windows you’ve created, as appropriate; **`resize_term()`** only handles *stdscr* and *curscr*.

PDCurses's `resize_term` (1998, version 2.3) came after ncurses's `resizeterm` ([1995](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-license.html#ncurses_1_9_3)), and rather than implementing the same feature, modified that (to resize the window rather than responding to the user's resizing it).  ncurses added a `resize_term` in [2002](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20020202) after *that* to solve a different problem.  The Git repo for PDCurses, by the way, only goes back to [version 2.4](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/tags?after=PDCurses_3_1) (I have tarballs).

PDCurses's documentation also needs some work, but the X11 port does respond to `SIGWINCH` (hence the `KEY_RESIZE` which it adapted from ncurses), but resizing the window rather than responding to `SIGWINCH` was what it did for the Windows version.

Comment: Thanks, just to check if I understood right, does it mean that on Windows OS, the resizeterm does not exist in curses library and hence the AttributeError message in the question, or it exists but only works if there is a resizing signal from the user?

Comment: yes - it "could" exist if the python developers chose to provide that in their binding, but a Windows console won't provide something like `SIGWINCH`, so that would be pointless.

Comment: The older versions of PDCurses are available on SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/

Comment: The Windows version actually supports both kinds of resizing, depending on the version of Windows (and whether you're using the old Console or the new Terminal, which I see is not handling either kind of resizing well yet).

Comment: sure, but the new Terminal isn't a Console (it's emulation of Console API is incomplete), and wasn't available when PDCurses's `resize_term` was introduced.  Most of the Python curses stuff far predates Windows Terminal, so while it may happen to work, that's only accidentally so.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what `curses.resizeterm` does, but if I replace it with `curses.resize_term` then it works as it supposed and it does what I want.

```py
import curses
def main( stdscr ):
    curses.resize_term( 20, 20 )
    stdscr.addstr( 10, 10, "o" )
    curses.napms( 3000 )
curses.wrapper( main )
```

And it should be called as `curses.resize_term` not `stdscr.resizeterm` as it is a method for curses and not a window object. The result looks like the following.

[image]

I guess it has to do something with backened something, there is a sentence in the manual, https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html.

[image]